# "Missing Context for Method Declaration" message in Xcode for - (BOOL)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm creating an app in Objective-C coding using Xcode. I am implementing the Moodstocks scanner into my app and have followed all the directions given in their step-by-step instructions. However, I keep getting a "missing context for method declaration" message for this one - (BOOL) part. Please be patient with me, I have no coding experience and have been making this app all on my own. Thank you.

Here's the section I'm having issues with:

```
    //  TBAAppDelegate.h
   #import "ScannerViewController.h"

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
ScannerViewController *scannerVC = [[ScannerViewController alloc] init];
scannerVC.scanner = _scanner;
self.window.rootViewController = scanner.VC;
[self.window makeKeyandVisible];
return YES;
    }
```

Okay, here's what the instructions I've been following say as well:

```
     // AppDelegate.h

    #import "ScannerViewController.h"

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // ...
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        ScannerViewController *scannerVC = [[ScannerViewController alloc] init];
        scannerVC.scanner = _scanner;
        self.window.rootViewController = scannerVC;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll need to post more of the surrounding file. Is this a method declaration inside an @interface block in a .h file? (In which case it should end in semicolon ";")... or is it the start of an implementation...

Comment: Where did you put that line? You should have a file called XXXAppDelegate.m, it should go in there (between an implementation line and the end, I can't post those lines to illustrate as it makes stack overflow go funny)

Comment: @Amino acids-- How would I do the implementation thing?

Comment: I'll post an answer so I can add more detail

Comment: When you  get an error, try Googling it. It'll save you beaucoup time!

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you create an iOS app you use a template within Xcode and that automatically creates some files for you, two of them are called YourAppNameAppDelegate.h and YourAppNameAppDelegate.m.

So you presumably must have these already? as they are the most fundamental thing to an iOS program.

When Xcode creates these files for you it also creates the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method for you and puts it in that file.

So ordinarily you would not need to add the method because its already there. 
So first of all check you have YourAppNameDelegate.h and YourAppNameDelegate.m, better still post the whole of those files into your question.

An error message such as your's could be generated if a method is not between the lines:

@implementation YourAppNameAppDelegate

…

@end

within the .m file.

So what is confusing in your problem is because the app delegate files, and the app delegate methods are created for you automatically by Xcode, how you came to end up with this error.
So you really need to post those app delegate files so we can see what's going on with them.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the post to contain more of the file

Comment: You can't put the "body" of a method's code into a .h file, it has to go into the .m file. Where the instructions say // AppDelegate.h must be a mistake, they mean AppDelegate.m. Go to your .m file and the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method should already be there, you need to paste the lines in the instructions into that existing method.